# i get a Fatal error when i try to connect mssql using php in wampserver

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, wampserver

I'm using **Wampserver (32bit & php 5.4I)2.4** **in windows 64bit**, will i install the 32bit becuse i need a connection to the MSSQL which required that as i know so far.

i downloaded the **Microsoft Visual C++**
and the php is a thread safe
so i added the two .dll files **(php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts , php_sqlsrv_54_ts***) to the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\ext*, then added them in the php.ini ( extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts and extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts), then restarted the wampserver
finally i gett an error says "**Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()**"
 the code that i use is :

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\instanceName"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB NAME");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

could anyone tell me what did i do wrong to cause this error?

Comment: I think this would be helpful: http://www.davidlauzon.net/2009/02/ms-sql-server-2008-with-php/

Comment: i forgot to mension this point , i did add the ntwdblib.dll and check the mssql extensions, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `phpinfo()` to see if the extension was loaded correctly.
2. If yes, see the error log for any issues encountered when starting apache (W**A**MP).
3. If yes, then the extension binary is wrong or you forgot to enter the file extension (.dll on Win, .so on Linux) in the php.ini.

Comment: i checked the phpinfo(), and the extension is not there. there isn't any error in the php error log

Comment: If it's not there in phpinfo and no error, then look at the 2nd part of point 3.

Comment: Looks good, are you sure you are editing the correct php.ini? Try making a deliberate syntax error to confirm.

Comment: yes i'm sure, it is the same php.ini i used when i connect to the firebird database which worked, but the mssql not yet and i don't know why :(